# Regex for matching argument of a function

Tags: regex

I'm trying to write a regex to be used in PHP to match the arguments of a specific function. Here's an example of the kind of things I'm trying to match:

```
$content = "myfunction('Text with (nested) parentheses')
            myfunction('Text2 without nested parentheses')
            myfunction('Text2 with variables ' + myvar)
            myfunction(myvar)
            myfunction(myvar1 + \"(nested) some text here\" + (error.length ? \" \" + errorMsg : \"\"))";

preg_match_all('/myfunction\(([^()]|(?R))*\)/', $content, $matches);
```

As you can imagine, all return except the one with the nested parentheses. The |(?R) is what I would expect would make it work. If I do this, however, things work as expected:

```
$content = "('Text with (nested) parentheses')
        ('Text2 without nested parentheses')
        ('Text2 with variables ' + myvar)
        (myvar)";

preg_match_all('/\(([^()]|(?R))*\)/', $content, $matches);
```

Unfortunately, I need to have the function name because I only want to match one specific function. Is that doable with a regex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a look ahead to exclude matching on close brackets when within quotes:

```
myfunction\((.*?)\)(?=(([^'"]*['"]){2})*[^'"]*$)
```

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/gRzogyRoHv).

This says "match a closing bracket that is followed by an *even* number of quotes" (recalling that zero is an "even" number). Characters within quotes have an *odd* number of quotes after them.

The reluctant quantifier `*?` will stop at the *first* such match, in case you have multiple matches on the same line.

Comment: much more elegant than what I was going to suggest. I can confirm that this works [link](https://regex101.com/r/iF0gN7/3)

Comment: This almost works. Added one case above that it fails to pickup. I've changed your regex to this: /myfunction\((.*?)\)(?=(([^'"]*['"]){2})*[^'"]*$)/ and it's even closer, the only thing it doesn't pick up is the last ) that follows the "" at the very end of the new test case I provided. Very close, and I can probably live with it if it can't be included

Comment: Oh, and by the way, thanks so much for this, even if I can't get it perfect, it will be useful enough in its current form.

Comment: @rocket just checking, in your language, is a doubled double quote an escaped (ie literal) single double quite? Let me know. Also, regex won't be able to handle combinations of quotes and double quotes - you'd need a parser for that, but if your input never mixes them then it can still work.

Comment: I'm looking at javascript files, so single and double quotes are escaped with a backslash, so \" or \'. There may be instances that use single quotes and other that use double, but there shouldn't be any case where you have both single and double within the parentheses. So you'd never have something like this: myfunction(myvar1 + "(nested) some text here" + (error.length ? ' ' + errorMsg : '')) . So in this example you have double quotes at the beginning and single quotes after, that wouldn't happen. Worse case I can run process twice to match single and double quotes with different regexes,